# when opening php page in browser characters disappear

Tags: javascript, php, html

In a html form characters seem to disappear when loading. Not always, but at some moments. I cannot see any reason.

The lines that should be loaded are:

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:158px; top:357px; width:25px; height:22px;">
    <select id="combo_60" name="lpostldid" size="1" ><option value="0">Kies een land</option><option value="30">Australie (AU)</option><option value="23">Belgie (BE)</option><option value="72">Denemarken (DK)</option><option value="24">Duitsland (DE)</option><option value="21">Engeland (GB)</option><option value="19">Frankrijk (FR)</option><option value="31">Italie (IT)</option><option value="22">Luxemburg (LU)</option><option value="28">Monaco (MO)</option><option value="29">Ned.Antillen (NA)</option><option selected="selected" value="1">Nederland (NL)</option><option value="0">Onbekend (--)</option><option value="25">Portugal (PO)</option><option value="52">Rusland (RU)</option><option value="32">Singapore (SI)</option><option value="20">Spanje (ES)</option><option value="27">USA (US)</option><option value="26">Zwitserland (CH)</option>>
    </select>
</div>
```

What I get sometimes are:

```
<d57px; width:25px; height:22px;">
    <select id="combo_60" name="lpostldid" size="1" ><option value="0">Kies een land</option><option value="30">Australie (AU)</option><option value="23">Belgie (BE)</option><option value="72">Denemarken (DK)</option><option value="24">Duitsland (DE)</option><option value="21">Engeland (GB)</option><option value="19">Frankrijk (FR)</option><option value="31">Italie (IT)</option><option value="22">Luxemburg (LU)</option><option value="28">Monaco (MO)</option><option value="29">Ned.Antillen (NA)</option><option selected="selected" value="1">Nederland (NL)</option><option value="0">Onbekend (--)</option><option value="25">Portugal (PO)</option><option value="52">Rusland (RU)</option><option value="32">Singapore (SI)</option><option value="20">Spanje (ES)</option><option value="27">USA (US)</option><option value="26">Zwitserland (CH)</option>>
    </select>
</div>
```

it is clear that the string `iv style="position:absolute; left:158px; top:3` is lost.
I think in about 90% of all loads things go well, but sometimes not.

Does anybody have an idea of the reason? I work with Firefox 30.0, the site is (until I can fix the bug) on my local machine (apache friends, xampp)

Comment: Please update question with code that generates this html. I also advise you to generate <div class='raymond'> ... and then set in your css .raymond { position:absolute; left:158px; top:357px; width:25px; height:22px; } this way it will be easier to maintain that code later

Answer (score 0):

You have a error in the syntax

```
<div style="57px; width:25px; height:22px;">
    <select id="combo_60" name="lpostldid" size="1" ><option value="0">Kies een land</option><option value="30">Australie (AU)</option><option value="23">Belgie (BE)</option><option value="72">Denemarken (DK)</option><option value="24">Duitsland (DE)</option><option value="21">Engeland (GB)</option><option value="19">Frankrijk (FR)</option><option value="31">Italie (IT)</option><option value="22">Luxemburg (LU)</option><option value="28">Monaco (MO)</option><option value="29">Ned.Antillen (NA)</option><option selected="selected" value="1">Nederland (NL)</option><option value="0">Onbekend (--)</option><option value="25">Portugal (PO)</option><option value="52">Rusland (RU)</option><option value="32">Singapore (SI)</option><option value="20">Spanje (ES)</option><option value="27">USA (US)</option><option value="26">Zwitserland (CH)</option>
    </select> </div>
```

In the two codes you got a extra ">" character in the options.